# Android: I need button to compare text view to date and go to new activity, my code is not working

Tags: android

```
public void onclick(View v) 
{

    {
        if (date.equals("30/10/2014"));
        Intent i = new Intent (this, A3.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    if (date.equals("31/10/2014"));
    Intent r = new Intent (this, A4.class);
    startActivity(r);
}   
}
}
```

i need button check if text view contains date for example "10/10/2014" go to activity A3
if text view contains date  "11/10/2014" go to activity A4

Comment: Does this even compile? Whats with the extra curly braces?

Comment: just check your code so many syntax errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you entered in your question is quite strange, so I'm not sure my answer is going to help you.

First thing is to remove ';' at the end of your 'if' statements.

Something like this :

```
public void onclick(View v) 
{


if (date.equals("30/10/2014"))
   {
   Intent i = new Intent (this, A3.class);
   startActivity(i);
   }

if (date.equals("31/10/2014"))
   {
   Intent r = new Intent (this, A4.class);
   startActivity(r);
   }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: im sorry its not woking